# How to prevent Entity Framework to request twice when accessing IQueryable

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I wrote an API using Entity Framework and I try to optimize its calls to the database.

When I retrieve an object (we will call it `Page`) that has many linked objects I use `.Include()` linq method which prevents N+1 calls.

My main object (we will call it `Book`) is having lots of `Page`. When I retrieve `Book` from db, I do it in 2 times in my DAL factory like that to prevent a massive single query (my `Page` has 10 linked objects & my `Book` got 4):

```
public async Task<IBook>GetById(int myBookId) {
    var Pages = myDbContext.Page
                           .Where(x => x.BookId == myBookId && x.IsChapter)
                           .Include(x => x.prop1)
                           .Include(x => x.prop2) etc

    var myBook = await myDbContext.Book 
                                  .Where(x => x.Id == myBookId)
                                  .Include(x => x.bprop1)
                                  .FirstOrDefaultAsync()

    myBook.Pages = Pages.ToList();
}
```

This is working and my generated SQL is exactly what I want:

```
select * 
from Page 
where page_Chapter = 1 and page_bookId = @EntityKeyValue1
```

and

```
select * 
from Book 
where book_Id = @EntityKeyValue1
```

with the `*` actually being the linked tables columns.

Now my problem is that when I try to convert my object from database object to front object, a new request is made for the `Page` which is

```
select * 
from page 
where page_bookId = @EntityKeyValue1.
```

Here is how I do the conversion :

```
public async Task<BookModel> GetBookById(int id)
{
       using (var context = _dalFactory.GetNewContext(EPurpose.SELECT))
       {
                var t = (await _dalFactory.GetBookRepository(context).GetById(id)).ConvertToModel();

                return t;
       }
}
```

and my `Convert()` method is :

```
public static BookModel Convert(this Book book)
{
        if (book == null)
            return null;

        BookModel toReturn = new BookModel
        {
           toReturn.Id = book.Id,
           toReturn.intP = book.intP,
           ...  
        };

        if (book.Page != null)
        { 
           var PageModelList = new List<PageModel>();
           //then I convert my book.Page to PageModel list and assign toReturn.Page to that.
        }
}
```

The request is made as soon as I check `book.Page != null`.

Any thoughts about how to prevent the double request? In reality I just need  around 10% of the `Page` retrieved in the last request

Comment: Presumably the second query is caused by code you've omitted.  But it might be Lazy Loading, which you can simply turn off on this DbContext instance.

Comment: Why don't you use the result of `GetById(int myBookId)` and map it to a  `BookModel`?

Answer (score 0):

Using [`.AsNoTracking()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking) may solve your issue, providing you don't plan to update those entities later.

```
 var myBook = await myDbContext.Book
                                  .AsNoTracking()
                                  .Where(x => x.Id == myBookId)
                                  .Include(x => x.bprop1)
                                  .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```